# Python/Django: export to MS Project

Tags: python, django, export, ms-project, gantt-chart

I'm looking for a Python/Django package able to export data (a list of tasks) in MS Project (or OpenProj or similar), but I've not found any.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

You may find that [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) will help you, although a little effort will be required!

MPXJ is a cross-platform library which runs in Java or .Net and provides import and export functionality for a variety of Project file formats. Depending on your target platform you may be able to use facilities such as Jype, Jython, or Pythonnet, to work with MPXJ.

Hope that helps!

Jon

p.s: Disclaimer: I maintain MPXJ.

Comment: Is it possible to build a Project-compliant XML file?

Comment: If you are referring to using MPXJ to generate an XML file which Project can read, the answer is yes.