# create ms project xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, ms-project

I am using python 2.7.

I would like to create a xml file like the one ms project creates. I need it (the file) to import it to RadiantQ jQuery Gantt.

any suggestions??
thank you

Comment: Are you asking about creating XML files, or about the MS project file format?

Comment: XML file. But with schema like the one MS project creates when you save project in MS project as *.xml. It is quite complicated so I thought there is a library for that or smth like for example for iCal standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net), if the platform you are working on allows interoperation between Python and Java or .Net.

Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295358/python-django-export-to-ms-project) with some suggestions for interoperability tools.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries available in python to deal with xml files. I personally used ElementTree. Below link is the summary tutorial for this:

```
    http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml
```

Comment: ok, but specific for MS project XML, is there a library such as win32com.client for word, excel???